# Start Google Chrome from cron task

Tags: linux, google-chrome, bash, cron

I'm trying to start `google-chrome` from cron task. Actually, I've a cron task checking every minute my chrome processes. If there is not any process. I want to start it.

Here is my cron task:

```
* * * * * export DISPLAY=:0; send-notify "`/home/myuser/.config/check_chrome.sh`"
```

I also tried:

```
* * * * * export DISPLAY=:0; /home/myuser/.config/check_chrome.sh
* * * * * export DISPLAY=:0 && /home/myuser/.config/check_chrome.sh
* * * * * google-chrome-stable -kiosk http://myawesomewebsite.com
```

Here is my `check_chrome.sh` script:

```
chrome_processes=$(pgrep chrome)
if [ "$chrome_processes" == "" ]; then
  sleep 3 && sh /home/myuser/.config/start_chrome.sh
fi
```

Here is my `start_chrome.sh` script:

```
$(google-chrome-stable -kiosk http://myawesomewebsite.com &)
```

My problem is that Chrome is never started..

When I check `/var/log/syslog` I can read the following sentence:

```
(CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

I'm not sure if it's linked to my Chrome problem or not.

Does anyone have an idea to show this Chrome window?

**P.S : I obviously start my script manually and it's perfectly working.**

Thank you in advance.

EDIT :

Here is my error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: send-notify: not found
```

[11940:11940:1203/142801:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(209)] Gtk: cannot open display:

Comment: 1 - error about MTA simply tell, cron can't send you an email with the error. 2- try adding >> error.log 2>&1 in crontba file to have a clue about the error.

Comment: Ok! I finally have an error! I've added it to my post

Comment: Add full path to send-notify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error is

> Gtk: cannot open display:

Try adding `xhost +` to allow graphic to acces your display.

Answer (score 0):

> chrome_processes=$(pgrep chrome)
>   if [ "$chrome_processes" == "" ]; then
>   sleep 3 && sh /home/myuser/.config/start_chrome.sh fi

export DISPLAY=:0